# Assign an array to struct fields in go

Tags: arrays, go, struct, assign

I have a struct with 8 fields of bool, and an array with 8 boolean values.

How can I assign each array value to corresponding field in struct?

I knew I can use `s.f = a[n]`, but what if there are more fields?

Comment: Go is free from magic and most syntactical suggar. Write code.

Comment: What if I have a struct with 15 or more  fields?! It seems cumbersome to use this @RedBlue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to set [exported](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) fields:

```
var y = []bool{true, false, true}
var x struct{ X, Y, Z bool }
v := reflect.ValueOf(&x).Elem()
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    v.Field(i).SetBool(y[i])
}
fmt.Println(x) // prints {true, false, true}
```